# Detect file change under document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, itunes

My app has iTunes file sharing turned on, and when user add a file in iTunes, it should be able to detect.

The following function from Application Delegate is used to be called
but not any more:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a solution: GCD. GCD allows you to create a `dispatch_source_t` that watches for vnode changes, like a write in a directory, and then notifies you about it. The basic is: Use the `open(path, O_EVTONLY)` syscall to obtain a file descriptor to the directory, then call `dispatch_source_create()`and pass `DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_VNODE` as type and `DISPATCH_VNODE_WRITE` as mask. Set the event handler using `dispatch_source_set_event_handler` and do whatever you need to do when a file is written in the directory, additionally you also want to set a cancellation handler that calls `close()` to close the file descriptor. Finally, call `dispatch_resume()` to start monitoring.

Comment: I like your approach! I didn't know about this one

Comment: @ThomasKeuleers It has become my go to method for file watching since I had to port some fsevents code to iOS. Dispatch sources in general are really awesome and powerful, and much under appreciated (just like dispatch groups, in my opinion anyways)

Comment: I recently used this gcd feature wrapped in a combine [publisher](https://github.com/kennethlaskoski/FileSystemEventPublisher).

Answer (score 0):

You could store a MD5 hash from the last file the app was working with.
Every time you start your app, you calculate a new hash from the file you are monitoring.
If the hash is different from the one you stored before, the file has been changed:

Here's a solution for calculating file MD5 hashes:
[Calculating MD5 Hash file](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/17659-calculating-md5-hash-large-file.html)

Comment: Then how do you get notified if it's changed?  You might as well just use the modified time and size of the file to detect change.  But that's not what the OP wants to know.

Answer (score 0):

The question is still valid if instead of detecting when files are added or removed from a folder you want to know if *any* file within the monitored folder was changed. I did not have any success in getting this to work with DISPATCH_VNODE_WRITE.

Yes, it is true that I get a DISPATCH_VNODE_WRITE event when a file is added, deleted or renamed within the folder (although there is a problem here too - to find out which of these 3 happened you will have to take snapshots of the folder's content and compare them - yuck!). But if an existing file from the folder is modified, I don't get *any* notification. I tried DISPATCH_VNODE_EXTEND and DISPATCH_VNODE_ATTRIB as well with no success.
This sucks because if you have a directory with hundreds or thousands of files, how are you suppose to find out if a file changes?

The deprecated Carbon [FSEvents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/) library was more flexible and powerful than the GCD + dispatch source approach IMO.